# Как правильно посчитать длину строки, содержащей кириллицу?

Tags: c++, строки

```
std::string str1 = "Test";
std::string str2 = "тест";
```

Я заметил, что
`str1.size()` = `4`, а `str2.size()` = `8`

Как это можно правильно посчитать?

Comment: Это зависит от используемой кодировки.

Comment: для того, что бы посчитать длину строки, нужно дать определение этой самой длины. Байты, code point (не знаю перевода), графемы. К примеру, возьмём строку "ё". Длина в байта может быть 2 или 4, в code point - 1 или 2, в графемах - один.

Comment: Посмотрите данный проект, возможно тут найдёте ответ для себя https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp

Comment: Похоже, ваши строки содержат тексты в кодировке [utf-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). По ссылке (в вике) хорошо описан принцип кодирования. Т.е. анализируя количество старших единичных бит в байте можно легко вычислить, сколько байт занимает каждый символ. Воспользовавшись этим знанием, вы легко можете написать свою функцию

Answer (score -1):

Кириллица занимает 2 байта на каждый символ, т.к. используется Юникод. Латиница и прочие символы занимают по 1 байту на символ, т.к. кодировка ASCII.

Возможно, вам нужен не size(), а length().

Смотрите [тут](https://ravesli.com/urok-202-dlina-i-yomkost-std-string/)

Comment: На cppreference читаем:

>Note that string objects handle bytes without knowledge of the encoding that may eventually be used to encode the characters it contains. Therefore, the value returned may not correspond to the actual number of encoded characters in sequences of multi-byte or variable-length characters (such as UTF-8).

Comment: Следовательно, ответ неверный.

Comment: для std::string length и size возвращают ровно одно и тоже

Comment: Да, согласен... невнимательно посмотрел